# check checkboxes build from async array of object with an @input array of object

Tags: angular, angular6

I try to create an html list of checkboxes with default values checked. 
I get an array of object from a service, and I want my list of checkbox to be checked following an array of object retrieved with @Input.

my object component looks like :

```
export class MyObjectComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() objInput: MyObject[];
  constructor(private myObjectService: MyObjectService) {}

  myObjects: MyObject[];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myObjectService.getMyObjects().subscribe(x => this.myObjects= x);
  }

  isIn(object: myObject, objs: myObject[]) {
    let bool = false;
    for(var i = 0 ; i < agcs.length ; i++ ){
      bool = this.comparer(objs[i], object);
    }
    return bool;
  }

  comparer(o1: myObject, o2: myObject): boolean {
    return o1 && o2 ? o1.Id === o2.Id : o2 === o2;
  }
}
```

**EDIT :** My `isIn()` function is wrong, I changed it to the following and it solved my problem :

```
isIn(object: myObject, objs: myObject[]) {
    for(var i = 0 ; i < agcs.length ; i++ ){
      if(this.comparer(objs[i], object))
        return true
    }
    return false;
  }
```

and in my html I do

```
<div >
    <div class="card-panel" *ngFor=" let obj of myObjects">
      <mat-checkbox [checked]="isIn(obj , objInput)">{{obj.Libelle}}</mat-checkbox>
  </div>
</div>
```

I get my @Input from an other object that is retrieved from a service too, like :

```
<div *ngIf="bareme">
      <app-myobj [objInput]="bareme?.MyObject"></app-myobj>
    </div>
```

`isIn()` function returns true or false as I want (I checked with a console.log) but all my checkboxes are still unchecked.

any thought about why?